# ESP8266 does not respond after changing baud rate to 9600

Tags: arduino-mega, esp8266

I have ESP8266 WiFi module and Arduino Mega Board connected. I use external 5 to 3.3 V regulator to power up the module. Common (-ve) line on the external power source and Arduino Mega GND is connected. Then I used 1K and 2K voltage divider for WiFi module RX and TX use as same. I am sure my circuit is well works.

Then I connect RX0-RX and TX0-TX. Then i put CH-PD to 3.3v

Then I opened the Arduino IDE and upload the Blink sketch. Done.. Then I opened Serial Monitor and set baud rate to 115200. Then power up the module. It gave me a lots of garbage values and ready. Fine.

Then I downloaded the FLASH_DOWNLOAD_TOOLS_v0.9.5. configure the 0x0000, 0x1000 and 0x7c000

1. SPI speed = 40MHZ
2. SPI mode = QIO
3. FLASH size = 4Mbit
4. 0x1000 = ai-thinker-0.9.5.2-9600.bin

Then O power off the module and connect GPIO0 to ground and again power on.

Then push start button. Then it downloaded to the chip. It worked. Done. Success fully uploaded. Then I again disconnected the GPIO0 and power on. Then I put AT and it results OK.

AT+GMR gives version 0.9.5 updated.done.

The problem was the module was responded for 115200 baud rate, not 9600. Then I:

```
AT+IPR=9600
```

it gives me nothing.

Now I can't communicate with it at either 115200 or 9600 baud. No respond whatever baud rate I put. Sometimes I am having same garbage values.

Comment: The command to change baud rate is AT+UART_DEF. Have you tried re-flashing the module?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue. Using the `AT+IPR` command seems to brick the module. Try to re-flash your module, like you did the first time. If it works, use this command: `AT+UART_DEF=9600,8,1,0,0` instead to change the baud rate.

Comment: Thank you reply me. I tried to reflash it. use baudrate 115200 .then the blue Led is blinking. after a little time blue LED went off. the software shows me to IDLE mode to Download mode but prograss bar doesn't update.it is stucked.

Comment: @KolithaWarnakulasooriya The flashing completed successfully? Have you tried sending AT?

Comment: No it didnt uploaded to the chip.software didnt show the success message.yes i tried to send AT. I set the end charachter type as Both NL & CR. baud rate 115200 ; nothing.

Comment: when i power up the module it gives me garbage values

Comment: Note:Serial port connected.    
Note:Begin find ESP8266.    
Note:ESP8266 ACK success.       
Error:Read ESP8266 register timeout.

Comment: chip sync ok!    .
chip_flg 1 ,
r1: 0a; r2:88 ; r3: 31,
MAC AP : 1A-FE-34-0A-88-31 ,
MAC STA: 18-FE-34-0A-88-31 ,
filename:   ,D:\Adruino\FLASH_DOWNLOAD_TOOLS_v0.9.5_150414\FLASH_DOWNLOAD_TOOLS_v0.9.5_150414\bin_tmp\boot_v1.1.bin_rep
offset :  0,
Erasing flash...,
head: 1 ;total: 1,
erase size : 4096,
erase flash error,
com closed,

Comment: Thank you for help me to figure this out. I have made it. http://www.pratikpanda.com/completely-format-erase-esp8266-flash-memory/ this was helped me

Comment: @KolithaWarnakulasooriya What did you change? Does it respond now?